# Get a listing of directories that have a certain folder within them (Cocoa)

Tags: cocoa

I am working on a Cocoa project (first one so I'm still learning) and I need to get a list of all directories at "x" location that also have a directory named "y" within them. I then need to populate a drop down box with the names of the "x" directories that have the "y" folder inside them. I will be using the drop down box selection to create and name a new directory later on.

I have looked into doing this with multiple different scripting languages but I have yet to find anything that works. I have also searched for a way to do this purely with Objective C, but the only thing I can find is ways to work with files, not directories. I am open to any way to do this, but being so new to Objective C and Cocoa in general, a simple way would be preferred.

If anything is unclear, just let me know and I'll do my best to clarify.

Comment: do you just want to get sub-folders of a directory x?  what's the meaning of "y"?

Comment: I need to get the names of all of the directories in the /Volumes directory,(these being "x") and then only return the ones that have the sub-directory "y" or in this case, "Users" Also, sorry for the long reply time. I've been very busy with summer classes.